# How can I add a new new field type "Tree"

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I wand add new field type “Tree” … in a new doctype named “Customer” I want add the “Territory” as link but it should be displayed as a “Tree” not drop down list and only the leaf should be selectable.
Thanks in advance.

I don't know how to start!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path but you can do it with one modification.

Using the get_query API on the client side, you can write an API to get the leaf nodes from the Territory tree and show them as a list on your field.